# SyncFusion Grid's filter is not working and the data is not shown as expected

Tags: grid, syncfusion

IN the syncfusion grid the filters are showing the correct and expected filters. But after a modal is being opened and closed it is giving an error and the data shown in the filter is hanged and only the last clicked filter data is showing.

The error is shown as :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_expands' of undefined
    at t.excelFilter._processListData (ej.web.all.min.js:10)
    at t.excelFilter.openXFDialog (ej.web.all.min.js:10)
    at Object._mouseClickHandler (ej.web.all.min.js:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (ej.web.all.min.js:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at a (ej.web.all.min.js:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.s (ej.web.all.min.js:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

I have tried many different things like setting the e-type as string and then showing the dataSources but nothing seems to help. Any help regarding can be really great.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query we suspect that you are facing an issue while perform filtering in the Grid. In this you also mentioned that after a modal is being opened and closed it gives the error, so we suspect that you have used the menu Filter or excel filter in the grid.

So, we have prepared a sample with the excel filter and tried to reproduce the issue but we did not face the mentioned issue at our end.

For your convenience we have attached the sample and please find the sample for your reference

Sample : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/313492/ze/filter_core-1339169973.zip

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/filtering/#excel-like-filter

If you are still facing the issue, kindly share the following details that will be helpful for us to provide better solution.

1. Share the complete Grid rendering code.
2. If possible please replicate the issue in the attached sample.
3. Share us a Pictorial representation or video demonstration of the issue.
4. Have you bound local or remote data to the Grid? If remote data which adaptor have you used.
5. Syncfusion Package version.

Comment: I had to use gridObject.destroy() on the modal grid . That resolved the problem. Thanks for the reply and the solution too.

Comment: @user15195016 how u fixed this issue can u explain me i got the same issue